# How to create 'although' sentences in Japanese

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, syntax, chinese

I know there are different ways to get the sense of 'although..., but...' in a sentence. Too many ways for me to be clear about how to express it at all, to be honest. In Chinese it's as simple as can be: 虽然。。。但是。Is there an equivalent in Japanese that suits most situations, independent from style and politeness level? Also, if you happen to know of a good Chinese-Japanese Dictionary I'd be more than happy with your recommendation.

Greets,
Touming

Comment: Ask a native speaker about "~~にしても、....". But, I think it can be deceptive because I think that "~~にしても、..." sometimes should be translated into the subjunctive mood, and "although ..." cannot be in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: Am I correct that what you need is a word translates "although", and "but" is not really relevant? Your Chinese 虽然...但是 seems to correspond to "although" altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To me, が seems to be the thing you're looking for. It is most commonly known as the "subject marking particle", but can also be placed at the end of a clause to create the sense of "although" or "but".

For example:

> 今日はいい天気だ**が**、遊びに行きたくない。
>   Although the weather is nice today, I don't want to go play.

This type of が can also be used in polite sentences:

> 私は日本に行ったことがあります**が**日本語がぜんぜんできません。
>   Although I've been to Japan before, I can't speak Japanese at all.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is very polite, but at least in a casual setting you can use のに:

> 天気がよかったのに、散歩に行きませんでした。
>
> Although the weather was fine, I didn't go for a walk.

I think a more formal way of expressing a similar construction is using ながら:

> 寒いながら、ジャケット着ずに待ちました。
>
> Although it was cold, I waited without putting my jacket on.

*Disclaimer: I am not 100% sure the example above are correct, probably a native speaker could correct me.*